# Hive Join - Reducer Issue

Tags: join, hadoop, hive

I am trying to join two big tables in hive.Even though i set the number of reducers to 500, the join happens only at the last reducer. Due to that jobs gets killed.
I understand that same key goes to same reducer. In both the tables, there are many unique keys. Can you please let me know how to resolve this issue. And also can you please let me know why the map reduce takes the last one reducer to perform the join.

Comment: Can you check the job tracker for number of reducers used in that Hive Job?

Comment: What is the type/format of your keys and are you specifying a partitioner?

Comment: Got the answer, one of the keys contains millions of records. So leading to a skewed join. Is there any way to eliminate it ?